# How to request https stream using YouTube iframe API?

Tags: https, microsoft-metro, youtube-api

I want to embed a YouTube player in my Windows store app on Windows 8.1. I use iframe to load a remote page:

```
  <iframe src="https://*.com/youtubepge.html"></iframe>
```

and in the page I import YouTube API:

```
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

I find that the player can be loaded but if click play button, the video cannot buffering and play.

I notice that, on Windows 8.1, there are a strict limitation about import remote content in metro app. And I remember that YouTube has mentioned that if import YouTube API using https,  the default video stream is under http, yet. So I think that the http video stream is blocked when mixed it with https content.

I do the same thing on Windows 8. Everything goes well. Because Windows 8 is not very strict restrictions.

How can I request https video stream on Windows 8.1 so that the stream is not blocked?

Comment: I have not done windows programming for a *long* time, but in order to use the YouTube player API you will have to be able to access the window.postMessage API.

This API is normally explicitly disabled unless your html is being hosted on a remote server somewhere (e.g. file:// uris and localhost  have the API disabled).

If you cannot access window.postMessage then you will not be able to use this API in your situation.

Comment: I also notice the problem. At first I use 'ms-appx-web' to load a local page(I import YouTube API in this page) as remote content in iframe. But YouTube's events can not be fired. So I put the page to a remote server and load it using 'https'. Then the player can be loaded and YouTube's events go well. But the video can not buffering can play on Windows 8.1(it works on Windows 8). I think iframe blocked the video stream on Windows 8.1. So I need a https stream.

Comment: Strangely, one time(just one) When I debug my code, the video can buffering and play on Windows 8.1(hmmmm...). And I notice the stream is under https(js console prompts me). I didn't change any code and run it again for many times, it didn't work any more. I think there are some conditions make YouTube API return https stream, but I do not know.